# Start VSCode with with integrated terminal opened

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VSCode to launch with the integrated terminal open? It's literally the first thing I **always** do - and it'd be great if I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently not possible in vscode.

Answer (score -2):

You can open terminal by shortcut

> Ctrl + `

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I want the integrated to be opened automatically without pressing ctrl-`. My MacBook is a bit older so it takes a bit of time to load the zsh, however starting `npm start` (or whatever - depending on the project) is in 95% of the cases the first thing I do. 

I might just end up writing an extension to do that for me.